# Android SwipeInterceptorView Using DroidQuery for A TextView

Tags: android, android-gesture, droidquery

I am using the [droidQuery](http://bit.ly/droidQuery) library to add some gesture detection to my app. I was having trouble adding the SwipeInterceptorView in my xml file (see original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126415/android-swipe-to-change-fragments-not-working), so I define it inside my `onCreate` method and give it the same parameters. Then I add it to my layout using `layout.addView(swipeInterceptorView)`. I attempted to add it to my `XML` layout file, but I got an error.

Is defining the `SwipeInterceptorView` programatically good practice, or should I add it to my `XML` file? If I should, how can I fix this `XML` file? :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <self.philbrown.SwipeInterceptorView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </self.philbrown.SwipeInterceptorView>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I use this layout, I get the *Runtime error* `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Also, i know how to add the `onClickListener` to an `ImageView`, but could anyone tell me how I should add the listener to a `TextView` also?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is defining the SwipeInterceptorView programatically good practice, or
>   should I add it to my XML file?

It is best practice to define the `View` in `XML`, since this provides a reusable file (so you can using it elsewhere in your app, or again in another app).

That said, it is not *bad* practice to instantiate it programmatically - it just reduces the reusability factor.

> how can I fix this XML file?

I am currently unsure as to why this is not working. I will be looking into it in more detail *ASAP*. In the mean time, one sure thing would be to download the entire project, import it into your workspace, and add it as a *library project*, rather than a *jar*.

> Also, i know how to add the onClickListener to an ImageView, but could
>   anyone tell me how I should add the listener to a TextView also?

You can add the click listener exactly the same way:

```
mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

If you want to make full use of the `droidQuery` library, you can optionally use one of these methods instead:

**click**

```
$.with(mTextView).click(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

**on**

```
$.with(mTextView).on("click", new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

**one** (only handles click once)

```
$.with(mTextView).one("click", new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {
        //your code
    }
});
```

**bind**

```
Object data = new Object();//could be anything
$.with(mTextView).on("click", data, new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ droidQuery, Object... params) {//data will be passed as a param
        //your code
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks. Also, how could I let the text-view detect a swipe? I tried doing the same thing as you showed my for the image-view in your previous answer, but it didn't work

Comment: @user2583347 you can put your `TextView` inside a `ViewGroup` - such as a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout`. This could be the same size as your `TextView` is now, and set your `TextView` to fill the parent bounds. Finally, add the swipe handling code to this parent `ViewGroup`.

Comment: thanks. do you know how to make the swiping less sensitive with the droidQuery library so you have to swipe longer?

Comment: @superuser you will need to change your implementation of the `swipe` function by declaring setting a class variable to the current time (`System.getCurrentTimeMilis()`) for the `START` event, then for each swipe event, check the time since the event started. If the interval has been long enough, you can react to it.

Comment: @superuser, again I think this would be best as a new question (where I can post some code). I will look for it soon.

Comment: I posted the question

Comment: also, after I added the swipeInterceptorView, this main function that you are showing me is never called.

Comment: @superuser did you call `view.setSwipeListener`?

Comment: yes. the swipeinterceptorview is registering the swipes. The other function is the one that is not working.

Comment: @superuser, which function? Can you say more?

Comment: the one that begins with $.with(v).swipe(new Function() {

Comment: it is defined in the onCreate method of my activity

Comment: @superuser, if you are using the `SwipeInterceptorView` in `XML`, you do not need to call this `droidQuery` method, which is simply a shortcut for adding the swipe interceptor and swipe detection for you. Instead, just manually call `setSwipeListener`. You will then also need to handle touch up and down events in the `onTouchListener` code.

Comment: I just asked another question about how to use the droidQuery library